# How to update input in shiny modlue from another shiny module?

Tags: r, shiny

I've got two shiny modules, with `updateTextInput()` in the ***first*** one. I want to update `textInput()` in the ***second*** module, when button from the ***first*** is clicked. I know it's  because those modules are in different namespaces but I can't figure out how to communicate modules.

Reprex below :)

```
library(shiny)

firstUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("update"), "Update 1st and 2nd module"),
    textInput(ns("first"), "Update me pls1", value = "Clear me!")
    
  )
}
firstServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      updateTextInput(session = session, "first", value = "")
      updateTextInput(session = session,"second", value = "")
    })
})
}
secondUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(ns("second"), "Update me pls", value = "Clear me!")
  )
}
secondServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      updateTextInput(session = session, "first", value = "")
      updateTextInput(session = session,"second", value = "")
    })
})
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  firstUI("module_one"),
  secondUI("module_two")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  firstServer("module_one")
  secondServer("module_two")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by making the first input$update reactive, then returning that value and making it reactive to the second server module. This way the second server module is "listening" to the change in the first one.

```
library(shiny)

firstUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("update"), "Update 1st and 2nd module"),
    textInput(ns("first"), "Update me pls1", value = "Clear me!")
    
  )
}
firstServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      updateTextInput(session = session, "first", value = "")
      updateTextInput(session = session,"second", value = "")
    })
    reactive(input$update)
  })
}
secondUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(ns("second"), "Update me pls", value = "Clear me!")
  )
}
secondServer <- function(id, clear) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(clear(), {
      updateTextInput(session = session, "first", value = "")
      updateTextInput(session = session,"second", value = "")
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  firstUI("module_one"),
  secondUI("module_two")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  clear <- reactive(firstServer("module_one"))
  secondServer("module_two", clear())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

A roundabout way would be to use `shinyjs` to trigger the updating manually.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

firstUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("update"), "Update 1st and 2nd module"),
    textInput(ns("first"), "Update me pls1", value = "Clear me!")
    
  )
}
firstServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      updateTextInput(session = session, "first", value = "")
      runjs('document.getElementById("module_two-second").value = ""')
    })
  })
}

secondUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(ns("second"), "Update me pls", value = "Clear me!")
  )
}

secondServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # Code not needed in here for now
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  firstUI("module_one"),
  secondUI("module_two")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  firstServer("module_one")
  secondServer("module_two")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Shiny modules work by giving each element a unique id by pasting `[module_name]-[element_id]` together in the html frontend, so each module server can correctly identify which it should be talking to. The first server can find and talk to `module_two-second` when passed that id directly. Ideally there might be a way of doing this within the Shiny code itself though.

### Edit: fix within Shiny by passing parent_session (without `shinyjs`)

The `updateTextInput` call can indeed find `module_two-second` itself if it can look outside of its own session environment. To achieve this, you can pass the `parent_session` as the argument to `updateTextInput` (defined in `firstServer` function definition and passed as `parent_session = session` in the `server` body):

```r
library(shiny)

firstUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("update"), "Update 1st and 2nd module"),
    textInput(ns("first"), "Update me pls1", value = "Clear me!")
    
  )
}
firstServer <- function(id, parent_session) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      updateTextInput(session = session, "first", value = "")
      updateTextInput(session = parent_session, "module_two-second", value = "")
    })
  })
}

secondUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    textInput(ns("second"), "Update me pls", value = "Clear me!")
  )
}

secondServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # Code not needed in here for now
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  firstUI("module_one"),
  secondUI("module_two")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  firstServer("module_one", parent_session = session)
  secondServer("module_two")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I like the edited answer here as we no longer need the `secondServer()`.

Comment: Thanks - your second solution should really be the top answer